# Just I am trying to implements simple Spring MVC projects then some kinds of error occurred in just like

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

My [servlet-context.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl2Jk.jpg)

[image]

When I make a new project in Spring MVC for Hello Spring Project:-

We have got this problem as shown in given image please help me how to fix the this problem:-

Comment: 1. Your link is broken. 2. Describe it here as much as you can, links going offsite are usually discouraged

Comment: The links works fine. I see an screenshot from the eclipse of the user

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use **context:**. See the [spring docu](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure that you have used XML schema correctly.
The following will work

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
           <property name="prefix">
               <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
               <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

     <context:component-scan base-package="com.hello.one" />

</beans>
```

Comment: @user3619040: geoand is right, you missed the `mvc` namespace declaration and the mvc namespace prefix in front of `annotation-driven`